# MIT License Creating a script that is illegal to use

Tags: licensing, software, open-source-software

Let me be clear on this. We are creating some Open Source scripts to gain more attention on our social media networks. These scripts are not legal to use because they break the Terms of Service of the target websites.

My question is, while it is illegal to use them, is it legal to create them? I wrote a disclaimer in the Github page that states:

This script should be used for learning purposes only. By downloading and running this script you take every responsibility for wrong or illegal uses of it. Please read Facebook Terms of Service and the MIT License for more information: https://www.facebook.com/terms

Is it ok or are we breaking any law?

This is an example repo: https://github.com/nerdsunity/nodejs-facebook-add-friends

Comment: How do you know if your script works or not unless you broke the law to test it?

Comment: @TTT ok but I could not test it. In fact it has no warranties. So what?

Comment: I would suggest removing the link to the script as it isn't relevant to the question. (Including the link makes it seem like you are trying to advertise your script, affirmed by the fact that the landing page even includes unrelated affiliate marketing.)

Comment: You didn't test it? That's like telling the officer that pulled you over that you were holding your phone to your ear but you weren't talking on it. But, you're right to ask "so what"... for the purpose of this question I agree it doesn't matter if you tested it or not.

Comment: Does "against the terms of service" == "illegal"?